# Xcode 6.3 beta 4 does not show values in debugger for linked frameworks

Tags: xcode6

I have an iOS (SpriteKit) project in Xcode 6.3 beta 4 with Swift 1.2 which bases on a custom framework (a second project of mine). Since beta 4 I can inspect the values of properties in the debugger of my main project, but not of the linked framework/module.

I tried to adapt the project properties `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy`, `Strip Linked Product` to `NO` (in `Debug`-mode), checked that my "Schemes" are set to `Debug`, and `Compiler Optimizations` are deactivated. But: no effect.

I have some screenshots but unfortunately I'm not allowed to post images with my reputation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do have the exact same issue

Comment: The problem is still there in the final version of Xcode 6.3 and 6.3.1.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 6.3.1 and 6.3.2